# Does a positive real solution exist to this problem?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I wrote the following code for getting the solution. I am not sure if the code I wrote is correct. The problem is further intensified by the fact that I don't know if a solution exists to this problem with the set constraints.

```
Reduce[1/2 (a Cos[k] + b Cos[k] + c Cos[k] - a Cos[k - 2 x] - 
      b Sin[k - \[Pi]/6 - 2 x] + c Sin[k + \[Pi]/6 - 2 x]) == 3/2 d &&
   x \[Element] Interval[{0, 2 \[Pi]}]  && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 1 > c > 0 && 
  d > 0, k, Reals]
```

Here, $a,b,c,d$ are constants and can take values from the interval $(0,1]$.
$x$ varies from $[0,2\pi]$. The desired solution i.e. $k$ must be a real number. So following are my questions:-

1. Is the line of code I have written correct? If not, please help me in rectifying it. If yes, please suggest me a way for arriving at the solution (if it exits).
2. Is there a way of just seeing if the solution exists for this type of problems without actually computing the solution?

Thanks in advance. Appologies if I haven't been able to clearly state my problem. Inconvenience regretted.

Comment: `Solve[1/2 (TrigExpand[
     a Cos[k] + b Cos[k] + c Cos[k] - a Cos[k - 2 x] - 
      b Sin[k - \[Pi]/6 - 2 x] + c Sin[k + \[Pi]/6 - 2 x]]) == 3/2, k]` produces a big expression. Too many parameters for `Reduce` over the reals.

Comment: If you set x==k==0 and b==c==d==1 you have a solution

Comment: @DanielHuber: But `k` is the unknown vaiable.

Comment: @DanielHuber I don't want a particular solution of the problem. I want the general solution of k for any arbitary values of a,b,c  and d, according to the set constraints.

Comment: At least you know that at least one solution exists

Comment: My weak comp can't effectively solve two-step problem: `expr = Solve[
    1/2 (TrigExpand[
        a Cos[k] + b Cos[k] + c Cos[k] - a Cos[k - 2 x] - 
         b Sin[k - \[Pi]/6 - 2 x] + c Sin[k + \[Pi]/6 - 2 x]]) == 3/2,
     k] // InputForm;Solve[k == 
   Piecewise[{{(k /. expr[[1]])[[1]], 
      C[1] \[Element] Integers}, {Indeterminate, True}}] && 
  x \[Element] Interval[{0, 2 \[Pi]}] && 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0 && 
  1 > c > 0 && d > 0 && C[1] \[Element] Integers, k, Reals]`. It would be useful if someone would try it.

Comment: You should update your question to include that you want distinct $a,b,c,d$. I believe I have shown that no such solution can exist, symbolically, as the square error over all $x$ is non-zero with these conditions.

Comment: @flinty I  think either your have answered a different question or your answer isn't right as from bbgodfrey's answer one can clearly see that solution exits even for disitnct a,b,c and d.

Comment: @user64494  I ran the code in your second comment above.  Three of my six processors ran for seven hours, using 6 GB of memory, and still have not produced an answer.

Comment: @SaliqShah What makes you think I answered a different question? If it's the integral throwing you off, think of it this way, if the equation is to hold then the lhs - rhs must equal zero over all x and (lhs - rhs)^2 >= 0. So if we take the integral of (lhs-rhs)^2 over all x from 0 to 2pi then we get some value >= 0 which we'd like to be zero exactly. Then solve for {a,b,c,d,k}. I showed a numerical result, but the reduce at the end with the distinct constraints tells me it's not possible this way - although close numerical solutions might exist.

Comment: @user64494  With respect to your first comment, the right side should be `3/2 d`.  With that correction and `Simplify` then applied to the answer,  the final result is much more complicated than my result, but the numerical result based on my numerical parameters is the same as my numerical result.  So, our two answers (after the correction) may be the same, although they do not look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved symbolically by means of the [Weierstrass Substitution](https://www.math24.net/weierstrass-substitution).

```
ex = (a Cos[k] + b Cos[k] + c Cos[k] - a Cos[k - 2 x] - 
      b Sin[k - π/6 - 2 x] + c Sin[k + π/6 - 2 x]) - 3 d;

Collect[TrigExpand[ex], {Cos[k], Sin[k]}, Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &];
Simplify[(t^2 + 1) % /. {Sin[k] -> 2 t/(1 + t^2), Cos[k] -> (1 - t^2)/(1 + t^2)}];
s = Solve[% == 0, t] // Simplify // Values // Flatten

(* {-((-Sqrt[3] b Cos[2 x] + Sqrt[3] c Cos[2 x] - 2 a Sin[2 x] + b Sin[2 x] + c Sin[2 x] +
    2 √(2 a^2 + a b + 2 b^2 + a c + b c + 2 c^2 - 9 d^2 + (-2 a^2 - a (b + c) + 
    (b + c)^2) Cos[2 x] + Sqrt[3] (b - c) (a + b + c) Sin[2 x]))/
    (-2 (a + b + c + 3 d) + (2 a - b - c) Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] (b - c) Sin[2 x])), 
    (Sqrt[3] b Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] c Cos[2 x] + 2 a Sin[2 x] - b Sin[2 x] - c Sin[2 x] + 
    2 √(2 a^2 + a b + 2 b^2 + a c + b c + 2 c^2 - 9 d^2 + (-2 a^2 - a (b + c) + 
    (b + c)^2) Cos[2 x] + Sqrt[3] (b - c) (a + b + c) Sin[2 x]))/
    (-2 (a + b + c + 3 d) + (2 a - b - c) Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] (b - c) Sin[2 x])} *)
```

and `k` is given by `2 ArcTan[t]`.  It is real, if

```
(2 a^2 + a b + 2 b^2 + a c + b c + 2 c^2 - 9 d^2 + (-2 a^2 - a (b + c) + 
    (b + c)^2) Cos[2 x] + Sqrt[3] (b - c) (a + b + c) Sin[2 x]) >= 0
```

Numerical values can be obtained by, for instance,

```
SeedRandom[1066];
r = Join[Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, 4]], {x -> RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}]
(* {a -> 0.480113, b -> 0.312575, c -> 0.457035, d -> 0.230827, x -> 3.62822} *)
sn = (k -> 2 ArcTan[#]) & /@ (s /. r)
(* {k -> 0.876737, k -> -0.892127} *)
```

Running numerous such numerical evaluations indicates that solutions are real about half the time.

Comment: See my comment to the question where `Solve` works without any substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can solve it numerically to get other approximate solutions besides those already discussed in the comments. Minimize the integral of the square error between left and right sides of the equation:$$\underset{a,b,c,d,k}{\mathrm{argmin}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\mathrm{lhs}-\mathrm{rhs})^2 dx$$

```
eqn = 1/2 (a Cos[k] + b Cos[k] + c Cos[k] - a Cos[k - 2 x] - 
      b Sin[k - π/6 - 2 x] + c Sin[k + π/6 - 2 x]) == 3/2 d;

eqz = (eqn /. Equal -> Subtract);

intg = Integrate[eqz^2, {x, 0, 2 π}];

{err, sol} = NMinimize[{intg, 0 < a <= 1, 0 < b <= 1, 0 < c <= 1, 0 < d <= 1, k > 0},
 {a, b, c, d, k}, WorkingPrecision -> 40];

(* the plot of the error should stay very close to zero *)
Plot[eqz /. sol, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

From this I get what looks like $a = b = c$ and the values:

```
{a -> 0.7407676298101783761156954580402392081913, 
 b -> 0.7407676298101783761455502947765225634654, 
 c -> 0.7407676298101783761328473487740510301014, 
 d -> 0.6130660961238245076636024095039218273303, 
 k -> 0.5959614992855459592789335254668571684626}
```

A solution with distinct $a,b,c,d$ doesn't exist:

```
Reduce[intg == 0 && 0 < a <= 1 && 0 < b <= 1 && 0 < c <= 1 && 0 < d <= 1
  && a != b && a != c && a != d && b != c && b != d && c != d
  , {a, b, c, d, k}, Reals]

(* False *)
```

Comment: I personally want an answer for the case when a,b and c are distinct

Comment: It's only by removing the distinct (not-equal) constraints that Reduce gives a solution:
```C[1] \[Element] Integers && 0 < a <= 1 && b == a && c == a && 
 0 < d <= a && (k == -2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a - d)/(a + d)]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||
    k == 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a - d)/(a + d)]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])```